# How to check when the user is typing in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am new to Xamarin Forms, and I want to check when the user is typing so I can change the text of the button

```
<Entry IsPassword="True"
       Placeholder="password"
       Style="{StaticResource InputStyle}"
       Text=""
       Margin="16,0,16,0">

<Button BorderColor="orange"
        TextColor="{black"
        Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
        Text="{Binding ButtonText}"
        Margin="25,0,25,0"/>
```

Comment: There is an Entry.TextChanged event that gets called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [TextChanged event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/entry#textchanged) in your xaml

```
<Entry IsPassword="True"
       Placeholder="password"
       Style="{StaticResource InputStyle}"       
       TextChanged="Entry_TextChanged"
       Margin="16,0,16,0">
```

And add this to your code behind page to catch it:

```
void Entry_TextChanged(System.Object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //do something here
}
```